# Hover over tabs and have it drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble having a dropdown with my code.
This is my html:

```
<!--Tabs-->
    <div id="tabbed-menu">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li id="tab-1" class="selected">Name</li>
        <li id="tab-2">About</li>
        <li id="tab-3">Comming Up</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="page" id="tab-1" style="display:block">
          <p>Brendon Baughn</p>
        </div>
        <div class="page" id="tab-2" style="display:none">
          <p>I am a 16-year-old programmer, still learning some HTML and CSS,
            JavaScript and jQuery.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="page" id="tab-3" style="display:none">
          <p>I am going to go to college for Computer Science and Programming,
          and hopefully become successful in life</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.tabs li').click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected") === false){
          $('.tabs li').removeClass('selected');
          $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
        var selectionId = $(this).attr('id');
        $('div .page').css('display', 'none');
        $('.page#' + selectionId).css('display', 'block');
      });
    });
```

I really need help with this. It will make my webpage look really neat (I have more information, but this is just some).
http://jsfiddle.net/BBaughn/so2bmkgg/
(the link doesn't go from tab to tab for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a couple of steps:

1. Change all of your `li.page` elements to `display:none`
2. Change your jQuery `click` event to `mouseover`
3. If you want the tabs to hide when the cursor leaves the menu area, add in a `mouseout` event.
4. I would also add `cursor:pointer` to `.tabs li:hover` for best practices.

Check out the jQuery documentation about [mouseover()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), as well as read through the complete list of [jQuery events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

See proof:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.tabs li').mouseover(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected") === false){
          $('.tabs li').removeClass('selected');
          $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
        var selectionId = $(this).attr('id');
        $('div .page').css('display', 'none');
        $('.page#' + selectionId).css('display', 'block');
      });
  
      $( "#tabbed-menu" ).mouseout(function() {
        $( '.page' ).css('display', 'none');
      });
    });
```

```css
ul.tabs{
      text-align: center;
      list-style: none;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      line-height: 26px;
      color: #0088CC;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    }
    ul.tabs li{
      margin-bottom: -1px;
      padding: 3px 10px 0px 10px;
      border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
      background: #EFEFEF;
      display: inline-block;
      border-top-left-radius: 6px;
      border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    }
    ul.tabs li.selected{
      background: #FFF;
      border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }
    ul.tabs li:hover {
      color: #333333;
      background: #FFFFFF;
    }
    div.page{
      text-align: center;
    }
    div.page li{
      text-align: left;
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    .tabs li:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Tabs-->
    <div id="tabbed-menu">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li id="tab-1" class="selected">Name</li>
        <li id="tab-2">About</li>
        <li id="tab-3">Comming Up</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="page" id="tab-1" style="display:none">
          <p>Brendon Baughn</p>
        </div>
        <div class="page" id="tab-2" style="display:none">
          <p>I am a 16-year-old programmer, still learning some HTML and CSS,
            JavaScript and jQuery.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="page" id="tab-3" style="display:none">
          <p>I am going to go to college for Computer Science and Programming,
          and hopefully become successful in life</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I want it to just have the tab name without the information. And then hovering over them will show the information. Right now I have the ".click()" until I find the replacement

Comment: That's awesome! what about when you mouseleave it and it closes? I tried .toggle but it completely closed the tabs